# Logistic regression model is ignoring most of my conditons

Tags: r, logistic

So I have a logistic regression model in R with 2 variables, year (integer-10 values) and faculty (factor with 2 levels).

For some of my year/faculty conditions, the number of successes were the same as the total number of cases (i.e proportion = 1.0). So when I produce my model is it ignoring these cases, and the model is significantly under predicting. How can I fix this?

Comment: Assuming you are using standard R packages, these cases will certainly not be ignored in estimation. That they are under-predicted (fitted) makes sense: you can't expect a perfect fit unless you are badly overfitting, and there is nowhere else to deviate from 1.0 than downward. If you can post your data and a minimal working example exhibiting your problem, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @StephanKolassa That seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using standard R packages, these cases will certainly not be *ignored* in the estimation.

That actual 1s they are under-predicted (fitted) makes sense: you can't expect a perfect fit unless you are badly overfitting, and there is nowhere else to deviate from 1.0 than downward. For the same reason, 0s will be "over"fitted, i.e., the fitted value will be larger than the observed 0.

If you can post your data and a minimal working example exhibiting your problem, we may be able to help you.

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)